# In the Django address module, how do I search for an entity by a related entity's column that isn't a primary key?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, filter

I'm using Django 3 and Python 3.7 with the django-address module -- https://github.com/furious-luke/django-address.  In particular, there are two models it provides ...

```
  Country
    name
    code

  State
    name
    code
    country -> Country
```

How do I search for states given a certain Country code?  If I'm just searching by primary key I can write

```
def get_object(self, pk):
    try:
        return State.objects.filter(country=pk)
    except Coop.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
```

However, I'm unclear how to write a Django query if I'm searching for states using a country's code.

Answer (score 0):

If your `country's code` isn't unique you can use:

```
State.objects.filter(code=your_code)
```

And if this code is unique you can use one of these ways:

```
# Way 1 
State.objects.get(code=your_code)
# Way 2 
State.objects.first(code=your_code)
# Way 3
State.objects.filter(code=your_code).first()
```

Hope it help!

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work.  The query rendered is querying against "state.code" instead of "country.code" -- ' SELECT `address_state`.`id`, `address_state`.`name`, `address_state`.`code`, `address_state`.`country_id` FROM `address_state` INNER JOIN `address_country` ON (`address_state`.`country_id` = `address_country`.`id`) WHERE `address_state`.`code` = 'US' ORDER BY `address_country`.`name` ASC, `address_state`.`name` ASC;'